# If a class contains object of another class can it be initialized by having default value in the constructor of containing class in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-value

Compiling this code produces the error

> `error time constructor time::time(int,int,char) cannot be overloaded with time::time(int,int,char)`

I'm trying to reduce overloaded constructors so I am trying to give default values in the constructor parameters. Is the line `entry(int sno=5,time t{1,2,'p'});` in the constructor for the `entry` class valid? If a class contains a complex object of another class then can it be initialized this way?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class time
{
    int hours;
    int mins;
    char ap;
    
public:
    time(int hours=0,int mins=0,char ap='n');
    time(int a, int b, char c): hours{a},mins{b},ap{c}
    {
    }
    
    void showtime()
    {
        cout<<"\nTime : "<<hours<<" "<<mins<<" "<<ap<<endl;
    }
};

class entry{
    int sno;
    time t;
    public:
        entry(int sno=5,time t{1,2,'p'});
        void showdata()
        {
            cout<<"\ne : "<<sno<<" : ";
            t.showtime();
        }
        
};


int main()
{
    entry e;
    e.showdata();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You clearly know the syntax for argument default values (using "assignment" with `=`). It doesn't matter if it's an `int` argument or an object, the syntax is the same.

Comment: Your error involves the definition of the `time` class, yet you ask about the `entry` class. That looks suspiciously like multiple questions or possibly an unwarranted jump to conclusions. I'd suggest making the `time` class compile before asking about the `entry` class.

Comment: the assignment part helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, this is just about syntax :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Time
{
    int _hours;
    int _mins;
    char _ap;
    
public:
    Time(int hours=0,int mins=0,char ap='n'): _hours(hours),_mins(mins),_ap(ap)
    {};
    
    void showtime()
    {
        cout<<"\nTime : "<< _hours << " " << _mins << " " << _ap << endl;
    }
};

class entry{
    int _sno;
    Time _t;
    public:
        entry(int sno=5,Time t = Time(1,2,'p')):
        _t(t), _sno(sno)
        {};
        void showdata()
        {
            cout<<"\ne : "<< _sno<<" : ";
            _t.showtime();
        }
        
};


int main()
{
    entry e;
    e.showdata();
    Time t2(5,2,'a');
    entry e2(3, t2);
    e2.showdata();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked!, can you explain why you put semicolon after each constructor, also when you write `entry(int sno=5,Time t = Time(1,2,'p'))` do you create a temporary time object and use that to initialize `time t`?

Comment: Ok,
semicolons are mistake, sorry.
I'm not an expert but i think if no argument is provided, then a Time object is created and used like if this object was passed as argument. So it's not a temporary object,

Comment: Semicolons after constructors are optional but generally considered poor style for being redundant